# Keep Activity in memory after returning results

Tags: android, android-activity

I have activity A starts B for results, I want B to return results to A and go back to A without finish() so when started again all properties will be the same before returning the results.

is it possible?

Comment: "so when started again all properties will be the same before returning the results" -- um, save that information somewhere outside the activity, then `finish()` the activity.  "is it possible?" -- not via `startActivityForResult()` and `setResult()`, if that is what you mean.

Comment: I know I can pass the data between intents and reinitialize them when activity B is launched, but I'm searching for "better solution", I don't want to exchange same data back and forth between intents.